# ReactJS Private Route for multiple user roles not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been struggling with for a bit of time and still cannot figure out how to make it work. I have a Private Route that should Switch between Client & Admin based on the user role.

Problem: If user role is client, it will display, if admin it will not display but the redirect it will be read from Client (client is the first Private route added but I don't know how to make them switch in between)

At the moment when logged in, it display only Client. When the user role is admin I want to be able to login as an admin. Client as a client, etc.

Some help would be much appreciated!

App.jsx

```
function App() {

  const NewComp = NewHOC(AppRoutes);

  //CHECK FOR USER LOGGED IN
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  const handleLogin = () => setUser(clientDetails);
  const handleLogout = () => setUser(null);

  return (
   <Aux>
      {user ? (
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>Sign Out</button>
        ) : (
            <button onClick={handleLogin}>Sign In</button>
      )}
      <Routes>
        {/* CLIENT ROUTE */}
        <Route path='/*' element={
        <ProtectedRoute redirectPath='/home'
                isAllowed={!!user && user.permissions.includes('star') && user.roles.includes('client')}
        >
          <div>The Client</div>
        </ProtectedRoute>} />

        {/* ADMIN ROUTE */}
        <Route path='/*' element={
        <ProtectedRoute redirectPath='/non-admin'
                isAllowed={!!user && user.roles.includes('admin')}
        >
          <div>The Admin</div>
        </ProtectedRoute>} />
        <Route path={"*"} element={ <Navigate replace to={ "/" }/> }/>
      </Routes>
  </Aux>
  )
}
```

ProtectedRoute.jsx

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
    isAllowed,
    redirectPath = '/',
    children,
  }) => {
    if (!isAllowed) {
      return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace />;
    }
  
    return children ? children : <Outlet />;
  };
```

Client Details

```
var clientDetails = {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Vio',
    permissions: ['star'],
    roles: ['client'],
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about isAllowed, but maybe what you really want to do is to use the loader attribute of a Router ? It is an async function that is used before the page is loaded. This way you have functions you can print things inside to debug !

Comment: The issue you’re facing might be due to the fact that you’re using the same path `(/*)` for both the client and admin routes. When the path matches, the router will render the first matching route it encounters, which in your case is the client route. So, even if the user is an admin, they will always be redirected to the client route because it’s the first match.

Comment: @ ohfufu It seems that without (/*) the child Routes of Client for example won't be rendered. You are right about first match as if I remove the client, the admin will work perfectly, but I cannot find a way to make them coexist and switch between them based on the user roles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you've two routes rendering on `"/"`, so only the first route is matched and rendered.

The `ProtectedRoute` should be rendered as a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) so it wraps nested routes that actually have paths, e.g. the protected content on actual routes themselves with the appropriate route path.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  const handleLogin = () => setUser(clientDetails);
  const handleLogout = () => setUser(null);

  return (
    <Aux>
      {user ? (
        <button onClick={handleLogout}>Sign Out</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleLogin}>Sign In</button>
      )}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" elemnent={<div>The safe home page</div>} />

        {/* CLIENT ROUTE */}
        <Route
          element={(
            <ProtectedRoute
              redirectPath="/" // <-- redirect to safe unprotected or non-client route
              isAllowed={!!user &&
                user.permissions.includes('star') &&
                user.roles.includes('client')
              }
            />
          )}
        >
          <Route path="client" element={<div>The Client</div>} />
          ... other client routes
        </Route>

        {/* ADMIN ROUTE */}
        <Route
          element={(
            <ProtectedRoute
              redirectPath="/" // <-- redirect to safe unprotected or non-admin route
              isAllowed={!!user &&
                user.roles.includes('admin')
              }
            />
          )}
        >
          <Route path="admin" element={<div>The Admin</div>} />
          ... other admin routes
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/" /> } />
      </Routes>
    </Aux>
  )
}
```